# Upgraded to JSF 2.1.22 and now PrettyFaces URLs are broken

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

As the title states, I recently upgraded to jsf to 2.1.22 to address an issue with nested ui:repeats.  Anyway, in doing so all my Prettyfaces URLs are no longer working.  Instead of the url:
`http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/91521`
I get 
`http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/%23%7bnavigationbb.visit.id%7d`

My URLMapping is as follows

`@URLMapping(id = "foo-bar", viewId = "/foo/bar.xhtml", pattern = "/foo/bar/#{visit : navigationBB.visit}")`

in my faces-config.xml

```
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>foo-bar</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/foo/bar</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <view-param>
                <name>visit</name>
                <value>#{navigationBB.visit.id}</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
```

and the urls are the result of the following

```
<h:link rendered="#{not cc.attrs.fooActive}" outcome="foo-bar" >
    <span class="status-arrow" />
    <span class="icon">1</span>
    #{messages.label_fooInformation}
</h:link>
```

If it matters, I am running on tcServer 2.7.2, Tomcat version 7.0.30, jsf 2.1.22, prettyfaces 3.3.3, primefaces 3.5, servlet 3.0.1

Comment: Ok, I did some more tweaking and it appears the problem appears between jsf-api version 2.1.5 and 2.1.6.  It appears that JSF is not evaluating the EL in my faces-config.xml file because I replaced `#{navigationBB.visit.id}` with a hard coded value of 22 and the URL renders just fine.

So this may not have anything to do with PrettyFaces... just JSF and perhaps SpringEL?

Comment: Seems to stem from this change:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2247

I don't know if my problem is the one Ed Burns describes on Nov 24th or if my problem has something to do with PrettyFaces.

Comment: I have tracked down the problem and created a JIRA issue for it:  https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2884

Comment: Thanks for digging into the root cause of this issue! I am also relieved that it is not our fault :) ~PrettyFaces Team